# Is there a way to reference an appsettings value within the Serilog section in appsettings?

Tags: .net-core, serilog, appsettings, serilog-expressions

Using [Serilog.Settings.Configuration](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration) (and presumably [Serilog.Expressions](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-expressions)) is it possible to reference another appsettings value? I'm trying to dynamically set endpointUrl below without duplicating the BaseUrl value or specifying the value outside of appsettings.

Serilog.Settings.Configuration has includes a section on their ReadMe around [IConfiguration parameter](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-configuration#iconfiguration-parameter), but it doesn't show an example assuming it's talking about what I'm referring to.

I tried the following solutions and none of them correctly set the value, except for the hard coded-duplicate approach.

```
"App": {
  "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:1234"
},
"Serilog": {
  "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.BrowserConsole", "Serilog.Sinks.BrowserHttp", "Serilog.Expressions" ],
  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "BrowserHttp",
      "Args": {
        // This works
        //"endpointUrl": "https://localhost:1234/ingest"

        // These do not work:
        //"endpointUrl": "{Concat(App.BaseUrl, '/ingest')}"
        //"endpointUrl": "{App.BaseUrl}/ingest"
        //"endpointUrl": "{App:BaseUrl}/ingest"
        //"endpointUrl": "{BaseUrl}/ingest"
        //"endpointUrl": "{AppSettings:App:BaseUrl}/ingest"
        //"endpointUrl": "App.BaseUrl/ingest"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IServiceCollection.PostConfigure<TOptions>()` to edit your options after being bound from configuration provider.

Options sample:

```
public class BaseOptions
{
    public const string SectionName = nameof(BaseOptions);
    
    public string BaseUrl { get; set; }
}



public class DerivedOptions
{
    public const string SectionName = nameof(DerivedOptions);
    
    public string AuthPath { get; set; }
}
```

Config sample:

```
{  
  "BaseOptions": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://localhost:5999"
  },
  "DerivedOptions": {
    "AuthPath": "/auth/login"
  }
}
```

Configuring:

```
var config = builder.Configuration;
var baseOptions = config.GetSection(BaseOptions.SectionName).Get<BaseOptions>();
var baseUrl = baseOptions.BaseUrl;

builder.Services.Configure<BaseOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(BaseOptions.SectionName));
builder.Services.Configure<DerivedOptions>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(DerivedOptions.SectionName))
    .PostConfigure<DerivedOptions>(x => x.AuthPath =  baseUrl + x.AuthPath);
```

Usage:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly DerivedOptions _options;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IOptions<DerivedOptions> options)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _options = options.Value;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(_options);
    }
}
```

This works, as you can see:

[image: debug options value]